# Service Activator without method in Spring Integration Java Config / DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

When using XML-based configuration for `service-activator` you can exclude the `method` as follows:

```
<service-activator input-channel="incomingCustomerChannel" output-channel="outgoingCustomerChannel" ref="customerService" />
```

This will cause the SI framework to choose the target method in `customerService` based on the payload. How can I achieve the same functionality using DSL and Java config?

At present I have the following:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow customerRequestFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from((MessagingGateways g) -> g.jms(connectionFactory)
                                                           .correlationKey("JmsCorrelationID")
                                                           .destination("customer_incoming.queue"))
                                                           .handle("customerService", "addCustomer")
                                                           .get();
}
```

The service activator is defined as:

```
@Component
public class customerService {

    @ServiceActivator
    public AddCustomerResponse addCustomer(AddCustomerRequest addCustomerRequest) {

        // add customer
    }
}
```

I have extended the activator to add a `deleteCustomer` method as follows:

```
@Component
public class customerService {

    @ServiceActivator
    public AddCustomerResponse addCustomer(AddCustomerRequest request) {

        // add customer
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    public DeleteCustomerResponse deleteCustomer(DeleteCustomerRequest request) {

        // delete customer
    }
}
```

I cannot simply remove the `, "addCustomer"` from  `.handle("customerService", "addCustomer")` as `methodName` is mandatory. Is it possible to achieve this in Java config / DSL?

Comment: I don't know how to convert that but you can probably achieve the same behaviour by using a `PayloadTypeRouter`, that is predefined in the [Spring Integration DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#message-routers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same `.handle()` using `null` for method name:

```
.handle("customerService", "addCustomer")
```

Or starting with [version 1.1](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/22/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-1-ga-is-available) you can use a new version of that method:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;
....
.handle(this.customerService)
```

Both variants do exactly the same what you have with just `ref` for `<service-activator>`.